# MySQL Query data where not equal column data

Tags: mysql

I am using this structure in MySQL

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `statistics`;
CREATE TABLE `statistics` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` int(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `machine_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `os_structure` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `os_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `os_version` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `processor_count` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `version` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `country_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED;
```

the query so far is this:

```
SELECT `os_name`, `os_structure`, COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `statistics` GROUP BY `os_name`, `os_structure` ORDER BY `count` DESC;
```

My question is how to get data but not from same `ip` column on `count` result, since I am not expert in statistics any improvement is welcome.
The following is the example of `os_name`, `os_structure`, `count` the true/false results is equal to 64bit system (for true) or 32bit system (for false) when I try to group by ip the results are more than expected I get many times `windows 7 professional` and its not what I want.

```
Microsoft Windows 7 Professional    True    36
Microsoft Windows 10 Pro            True    26
Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate        False   12
Microsoft Windows 7 Professional    False   11
Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate        True    5
Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise      False   1
Microsoft Windows 7 Professional N  True    1
Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate K      False   1
```

Comment: 'how to get data but not from same ip column on count result' -  I'm going to need a bit more than that.

Comment: If you want count separated for each `ip`, try adding it in `group by` clause, so it is `GROUP BY ip, os_name, os_structure`

Comment: I edited and gave the example and more info. if I group by `ip` the results are more than expected I get many times windows 7 professional and its not what I want.

Comment: What is it you do want then? An example would be helpful.

Comment: Microsoft Windows 7 Professional    True    36 I would like to remove the same `ip` from the number 36, imagine there is 10 (out of 36) results that have same `ip` the number I want in result is 27 cause they have same `ip` (keep the 1 out of 10 same `ip`'s) as result

Comment: Perhaps a count(distinct ip).

Comment: I don't understand what distinct does but it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a count(distinct )

for example

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select status,username from users;
+--------+----------+
| status | username |
+--------+----------+
|     14 | John     |
|     13 | Jane     |
|     12 | Ali      |
|     11 | Bruce    |
|     10 | Martha   |
|      9 | Sidney   |
|      8 | charlie  |
|      7 | Elisa    |
|      6 | Samantha |
|      5 | Hannah   |
|      5 | Hannah   |
|      3 | Kevin    |
+--------+----------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> select status,count(*), count(distinct username) from users group by status;
+--------+----------+--------------------------+
| status | count(*) | count(distinct username) |
+--------+----------+--------------------------+
|      3 |        1 |                        1 |
|      5 |        2 |                        1 |
|      6 |        1 |                        1 |
|      7 |        1 |                        1 |
|      8 |        1 |                        1 |
|      9 |        1 |                        1 |
|     10 |        1 |                        1 |
|     11 |        1 |                        1 |
|     12 |        1 |                        1 |
|     13 |        1 |                        1 |
|     14 |        1 |                        1 |
+--------+----------+--------------------------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note status 5.